# Jackson mapping POST parameters to Java POJO

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

I am writing a Spring RESTful service which consumes JSON and performs some action. As the request contains a large number of parameters, I thought of mapping my request parameters to Java object using Spring's Jackson mapping.

**My POJO**

```
public class RequestInput {

 private int id;
 private String name;
 // parameters follow


 // getter and setter
}
```

**My controller**

```
@Controller
public class RequestController{

   @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/rest/postRequest")
   public void handleRequest(@RequestBody RequestInput input){
          // code follows
   }

}
```

Things work fine when the data is posted as

> {"id" : 1, "name" : "ABCD"}

but  when data is posted as

> {"id" : 1, "first_name" : "ABCD"}

value of name in object is being returned as `NULL`.

Can you please help me in understanding how I can map first_name in request to name param in Java POJO

Comment: How would Jackson know, if you wont tell it, what to do. Guessing, that "name" and "first_name" should map to "name" is a bit too hard.

Comment: @ThomasJunk solution suggested by wsl below works. JsonProperty annotation informs the framework which input key to map to which param in pojo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@JsonProperty`. Annotate your `RequestInput`  class:

```
public class RequestInput {
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: If everything is ok please check it as accepted answer, will help others who have same poblem :-)